# Clarity Design how to use e.g. .clr-row, only possible inside of content-area?

Tags: vmware-clarity

Maybe this is a basic question, if I copy the below code into a `<div class="main-container"></div>` the window will show the horizontal scroll, but if the code goes to a `<div class="content-area"></div>` then I have the expected behavior.

```html
<div class="clr-row">
    <div class="clr-col-4">
        <span>4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clr-col-6">
        <span>6</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clr-col-2">
        <span>2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

e.g. the `.clr-row` must be only used inside a *content-area* ? 
I'm using **Angular 9** with **Clarity Design 3.0.0-next.8**.

Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use `clr-row` inside of the `.content-area` container element.

We disucuss application layout and how it fits with the variaous navigation patterns here: https://v2.clarity.design/app-layout

But its not explicitly called out to use the layout classes and apply them to elements inside of the content-area.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation.